# Get filtered array by some with multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, filter, array-filter, searchfiltercollection

This is the structure of my arrays:-

`projects` array:-

```js
let projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Project 1',
        techs: [
            id: 1
            name: 'Tech 1'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Project 2',
        techs: [
            id: 1
            name: 'Tech 2'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Project 3',
        techs: [
            id: 1
            name: 'Tech 3'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Project 4',
        techs: [
            id: 1
            name: 'Tech 1'
        ]
    }
]
```

Right now I'm able to get **only filtered projects of just Tech 1** as shown below:-

```js
let filteredProjs = projects.filter(proj => proj.techs.some(tech => tech.name === 'Tech 1'))
```

I want to get **filtered** projects of **Tech name = 'Tech 1' & 'Tech 2'**. But it `return` me nothing when I did as shown below:-

```js
let filteredProjs = projects.filter(proj => proj.techs.some(tech => tech.name === 'Tech 1' && tech.name === 'Tech 2'))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to try OR operator (`||`) instead of AND (`&&`).

In Computer Programming, `AND` returns `true` only when conditions on both the sides evaluates to `true`.
In case of `OR`, it evaluates to `true` if either of the conditions on any side returns `true`.

In your case I assume you want to filter out projects in which Tech name equals 'Tech 1' `OR` 'Tech 2'.

Comment: Strangely enough, this WORKS! I thought I need to do `&&` in order to get all projects that have tech of **Tech 1** `AND` **Tech 2**. But by doing so, it returns me `false` as you said. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Nothing strange about it... It's basic. I would recommend you read about it from - https://javascript.info/logical-operators. They work similarly in most of the programming langauges. If you think the above answer is correct, please feel free to upvote and accept as an answer. Otherwise please feel free to suggest on how it can be improved.